# Objective-c basics: Object declared in MyAppDelegate not accessible in another class

Tags: objective-c, declaration

I have an object declared in my app delegate:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    ClassName *className;
}
```

In another class, I include the app delegate:

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@implementation AnotherClass
-(void)doMethod {
    [className doClassNameMethod];
}
```

This fails at compile time due to *className* being undeclared. Shouldn't it be accessible, since I've included the MyAppDelegate, where className is declared? I need AnotherClass.doMethod to be accessing the same instance that is created in MyAppDelegate.

Any help on this would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't "@implementation AnotherClass"  be  "@implementation MyAppDelegate"?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Objective-C Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

Comment: It's hard to think of a name for an object pointer that's worse than className, or a worse name for a class than ClassName.

Comment: @Twelve47: I see what you're thinking, but no. The OP specifically states this is from another class. @Caleb: I tried to generalize this as much as possible for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a instance variable in one class from another class, you should create a property.

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    ClassName *className;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) ClassName *className;

...
@end
```

From the other class you may then access this property like this:

```
@implementation AnotherClass
- (void) doMethod {
    MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.className doClassNameMethod];
}
@end
```

Comment: The UIApplication message was exactly what I needed. I was able to point to the proper instance and get the show back on the road. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How should your other class know about this variable in the first place?

What you have posted here, shows that instances of your `AppDelegate` class have a member named `className`, that is of type `ClassName`. This means that in every instance-method of the `AppDelegate-class` (the ones starting with a minus sign) you can access that variable by the name `className`.

This, however, does **not** mean you can directly access this variable from anywhere else! In fact, the exact opposite is much closer to the truth.

If you want to access that variable from somewhere else, there are a couple of options — the probably most common one would be to provide an accessor method for it (and for doing this, there are again a couple of options).

Consider the following:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
  NSMutableString *interestingMember;
  NSMutableString *inaccessibleMember;
}
-(NSMutableString*)interestingMember;
@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
}
-(void)appendString:(NSString*) toMemberOfObject:(ClassA*);
@end
@implementation ClassB
-(void)appendString:(NSString*)string toMemberOfObject:(ClassA*)object
{
  [[object interestingMember] appendString:string]; //this will work: you can access the variable through its accessor
  [inaccessibleMember length]; // this will give a compile error, because the variable is undefined in the current scope
}
@end
```

Since this is the fairly basic bread & butter stuff of OOP, I'd encourage you to read [Learning Objective C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) and some of the other introductory material on Apple's website.

Answer (score 1):

The `className` is not within the scope of `AnotherClass`, it does not inherit anything from `MyAppDelegate`, you can create a `MyAppDelegate` object in `AnotherClass` and utilize the `className` variable for your uses but you still need to use the accessor methods in `MyAppDelegate` to talk to it.

TLDR: `#import "MyAppDelegate.h"` only allows you to create a `MyAppDelegate` object in `AnotherClass` not use the instance variables within that class.

What are you trying to do exactly within these two classes?